# Tableau 9.3 Dateparse function returning only one month instead of 12

Tags: tableau-api

I have 12 columns in my data, named as Jan, Feb, Mar to Dec. To convert them into Date format I am using 
DATEPARSE("MMM",[Month])
But this returns only Q1 and January

When I did the same thing in Tableau 9.2 this worked absolutely fine.

Is there something else I can try in Tableau 9.3

Comment: A month name by itself is not a date. It's only part of a date. Dates are composite types. Post a few lines of example data, and a few lines showing what you'd like to achieve

Comment: My month column contains only month name and is read as string. To convert into date format used this DATEPARSE("MMM",[Month]).

Comment: In tableau 9.2 i got all the months by using the converted field but in 9.3 only  got one month. Had shared this problem on tableau community and it has been accepted as a bug. You can check the complete discussion [here](https://community.tableau.com/thread/211287)